# Can't use MIN, MAX etc. SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have this kind of query:

```
 select 
      FirstName, LastName, BirthDate,
      GETDATE() AS [Today],
      CAST (DATEDIFF (DD, BirthDate, GETDATE())/365.25 AS INT) AS [Age]
FROM
      Employees
WHERE CAST (DATEDIFF (DD, BirthDate, GETDATE())/365.25 AS INT) >=55
ORDER BY LastName ASC
```

And I want to find the greatest, the smallest and average age and I thought I could do this but apparently I can't. How to make this work ?

```
 select 
     FirstName, LastName, BirthDate,
     GETDATE() AS [Today],
     CAST (DATEDIFF (DD, BirthDate, GETDATE())/365.25 AS INT) AS [Age],
     MIN (DATEDIFF (DD, BirthDate, GETDATE())/365.25 AS INT)
FROM
     Employees
WHERE 
     CAST (DATEDIFF (DD, BirthDate, GETDATE())/365.25 AS INT) >=55
ORDER BY 
     LastName ASC
```

Error:

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 5
>   'MIN' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: _"apparently i can't"_ do you get any informations like an error?

Comment: Yes, it says now: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'MIN'.

Before it was that there is no MIN function..

Comment: You are missing a comma after the previous line

Comment: I added a coma and the error now is: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 5
'MIN' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Any reason for the asterisks? Please post the exact SQL you are running...

Comment: Asterixes were created when i highlighted the text like BOLD when creating the question here.

Comment: Is this the only part of your code?

Comment: Yes. The first part in question works, but when i try to use min or max or avg it doesn't.

Comment: if you want to use an aggregate function like MIN(), you need a GROUP BY  clause.  Also, try testing for 55 yrs by adding 55 yrs to their DOB and comparing with GETDATE(), instead of dividing the number of days by a floating-point value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution which I have found. Thanks to everyone for their help!

```
SELECT
       MAX (CAST (DATEDIFF (DD, BirthDate, GETDATE())/365.25 AS INT)) AS [The Biggest Age]
     , MIN (CAST (DATEDIFF (DD, BirthDate, GETDATE())/365.25 AS INT)) AS [The Smallest Age]
     , AVG (CAST (DATEDIFF (DD, BirthDate, GETDATE())/365.25 AS INT)) AS [The Average Age]
FROM
      Employees
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select FirstName
     , LastName
     , BirthDate
     , GETDATE() AS [Today]
     , CAST (DATEDIFF (DD, BirthDate, GETDATE())/365.25 AS INT) AS [Age]
     , MIN (CAST (DATEDIFF (DD, BirthDate, GETDATE())/365.25 AS INT))
FROM  Employees
GROUP BY FirstName
     , LastName
     , BirthDate
     , CAST (DATEDIFF (DD, BirthDate, GETDATE())/365.25 AS INT) 
HAVING CAST (DATEDIFF (DD, BirthDate, GETDATE())/365.25 AS INT) >=55
ORDER BY LastName ASC
```

Comment: Still...
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 6
'MIN' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: execute `SELECT @@VERSION` in your management studio and show the results here please.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2218.0 (X64) 
 Jun 12 2012 13:05:25 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Comment: @PirreLeSang Copy and past this answer exactly. Your problem in your original question was that you were missing `CAST` and selecting `MIN(date AS INT)` which is invalid and will give you the error message you mentioned. However, there is no logical reason why this shouldn't work

Comment: @Sam cd which answer should i copy and paste ? Can you please write the right answer for me to run ?

Comment: Now i get this:
Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Comment: @PirreLeSang That is probably a reference to `GETDATE()`. You can't group by `GETDATE()`

Comment: @Sam cd then what would you suggest me to do ?

Comment: @PirreLeSang You don't need it. Just copy and paste the whole query from this answer. It has already been edited so that `GETDATE()` has been removed from the `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: @Sam cd it's working but it doesn't show me the max or the min or avg age, it just copies the Age column like this
http://i.imgur.com/UglbPB2.png

Answer (score 0):

A few edits to @MAli answer. You don't need GETDATE() in the GROUP BY clause, and grouping by the same value that you are getting MIN for will just give you the same value. This should be your query:

```
SELECT FirstName,LastName,BirthDate,Today,Age,
       MIN(Age) OVER ()
FROM (
    select FirstName
         , LastName
         , BirthDate
         , GETDATE() AS [Today]
         , CAST (DATEDIFF (DD, BirthDate, GETDATE())/365.25 AS INT) AS [Age]
    FROM  Employees
    GROUP BY FirstName
         , LastName
         , BirthDate 
    HAVING CAST (DATEDIFF (DD, BirthDate, GETDATE())/365.25 AS INT) >=55
    ) AS A
ORDER BY LastName ASC
```

Comment: sry but for some reason still the same, no min or max http://i.imgur.com/z44ejO2.png

Comment: @PirreLeSang Yes, that is probably because people with the same birthday will generally have the same age. I fixed it. Try it now.

Comment: still nothing. Maybe i didn't write correctly what i need cause i'm a little noob, so let me rephrase. Is it possible to count the age as i did and   after i counted the age show the youngest one and the oldest one ? I thought that by using MIN i can return the youngest one.

Comment: GREAT! Big thanks to you, didn't now that edited is clickable :D