# Date difference / time span between between punch in / punch out events

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

We have a SQL Server database that records the date and time of when someone swipes their ID  card at a number of different card readers, as well other information such as the person's ID number, the number and name of the card swipe (location), etc. Each swipe is a separate transaction on its own row. I've been asked to create a report (ideally in SSRS) that calculates the difference between when someone punches in and when the punch out - essentially when they punch at one of two card readers, and punch out at one of two card readers. The relevant data in the database is similar to this:

| TRANSACK_ID | Time | TR_SLA | TR_DEV_NAME | TR_MASTER_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 41506 | 2021-12-16 09:18:33.000 | 03010302 | Gate 1 (In) | 33 |
| 41684 | 2021-12-16 17:08:32.000 | 03010303 | Gate 1 (Out) | 33 |
| 41131 | 2021-12-15 07:10:46.000 | 03010302 | Gate 1 (In) | 80 |
| 41326 | 2021-12-15 15:34:58.000 | 03010303 | Gate 1 (In) | 80 |

The query that I have to pull the relevant data is:

```
SELECT TRANSACK_ID, CAST(TRANSACK.TR_DATETIMELOCAL AS datetime) AS Time, TR_SLA, TR_DEV_NAME, TR_MASTER_ID
FROM TRANSACK
where (TRANSACK.TR_SLA = '03010301' OR TRANSACK.TR_SLA = '03010302' OR TRANSACK.TR_SLA = '03010303' OR TRANSACK.TR_SLA = '03010304')
GROUP by TR_MASTER_ID, TRANSACK_ID, TR_DATETIMELOCAL, TR_COMP_NAME, TR_DEV_NAME, TR_SLA
order by TR_MASTER_ID
```

I can use this query to populate a dataset in SSRS.  What I can't figure out is how to calculate the difference in time between each Gate 1 (In) row and Gate1 (Out) row, per each ID in the TR_MASTER_ID column. I've tried all the datediff expressions that I can think of in SSRS without any success, but am probably missing something obvious.

Any suggestions or input would be appreciated.

Comment: GROUP BY, but no set functions. Why not just SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: Is that actual sample data or the result of a query? You can't have duplicate column names in a table and a column called `Time` should really contain *times*

Comment: @Stu, sorry, that was a typo in the column name.  I've fixed the typo with the correct column name.

Comment: You still have two `TRANSACK_ID` columns though

Comment: @jarlh, thanks for the suggestion, it looks like GROUP BY isn't needed.

Comment: Stu, thanks.  I've fixed that column as well.

Comment: Is `03010301` supposed to be a **number** or a **string**? If a number, then why do you have a leading zero?

Comment: Your data or description is still rather ambiguious, *...per each user ID* - what User Id? You don't have a column called *User Id*

Comment: @SMor, It's a string. The datatype for the TR_SLA column is varchar.

Comment: If TR_SLA is varchar then why is it not quoted in your sample query? That's going to results in an ambiguous implicit cast.

Comment: @Stu, the user id is the value in the TR_MASTER_ID column.  I've edited my question to hopefully clarify.

Comment: @Stu, still learning.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I've updated the sample query.

Comment: Are there only ever two rows for each `TR_SLA` one for `In` and one for `Out`?

Comment: You might get a better response if you show your raw data and desired result even if it is mocked up.. a SQL Fiddle to recreate the data would be handy so we don't have to waste time recreating your data!

Answer (score 0):

I added `PunchStatus` to express if the employee punched correctly. I also evaluated first punch of 'in' and last punch of 'out' as the punches, in order to prevent multiple punches. You can change that part if you want. You can try the following and see how many hours elapsed between punches for an employee in a day:

```
SELECT TR_MASTER_ID,
        PunchDate
        CASE 
           WHEN FirstPunchTime IS NULL THEN 'No Punch In'
           WHEN LastPunchTime IS NULL THEN 'No Punch Out'
           WHEN FirstPunchTime IS NOT NULL AND LastPunchTime IS NOT NULL THEN 'Success'
        END AS PunchStatus,
        CASE 
           WHEN FirstPunchTime IS NOT NULL AND LastPunchTime IS NOT NULL THEN 
                DATEDIFF(second, FirstPunchTime, LastPunchTime) / 3600.0 END AS TimeElapsedInHours
FROM
(SELECT TR_MASTER_ID,
        CAST(CAST(TRANSACK.TR_DATETIMELOCAL AS datetime) AS date) AS PunchDate,
        MIN(CASE WHEN TR_DEV_NAME LIKE '%(In)%' THEN CAST(TRANSACK.TR_DATETIMELOCAL AS datetime) END AS PunchInTime) AS FirstPunchTime,
        MAX(CASE WHEN TR_DEV_NAME LIKE '%(Out)%' THEN CAST(TRANSACK.TR_DATETIMELOCAL AS datetime) END AS PunchInTime) AS LastPunchTime
FROM TRANSACK
GROUP BY TR_MASTER_ID,
        CAST(CAST(TRANSACK.TR_DATETIMELOCAL AS datetime) AS date)) AS T
```

Expected output:

| TR_MASTER_ID | PunchDate | PunchStatus | TimeElapsedInHours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 33 | 2021-12-16 | Success | 7.8 |
| 80 | 2021-12-15 | No Punch Out |  |

Comment: thank you for the example.  I'm getting " 'MIN' is not a recognized built-in function name" and " 'MAX' is not a recognized built-in function name" errors when I  run your query in SSMS.  I'll try to work through those errors further.

Comment: Which version of SSMS you are using? Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010763/cant-use-min-max-etc-sql-server-2012) if you have a similar issue.

Comment: I'm using SSMS version 18.10.  I'll take a look at the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

This is what we used to accomplish our goal:

```
cast( (cast(TR_DATETIMELOCAL as datetime) - lag(TR_DATETIMELOCAL) over (order by TR_MASTER_ID, TR_DATETIMELOCAL)) as time) as diff from TRANSACK
```

The statement was found here: [Calculate Time Difference Between Two Consecutive Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39877919/calculate-time-difference-between-two-consecutive-rows)